# vuejs Google map info Window - hide close icon

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2, quasar

I would like to know how could I possibly Hide/Remove the close icon in google-map infoWindow.

[image: info window]

I am using Vuejs with [Gmap-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmap-vue) a port of [vue-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps)

**template**

```
<GmapMap
  ref="mapRef"
  :center="center"
  :zoom="12"
  :style="`height: ${mapSize.height}; width: ${mapSize.width};`"
  :options="mapOptions"
>
  <gmap-info-window
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :key="index"
    :options="infoOptions"
    :position="m.position"
    :opened="showInfoWindow"
    @closeclick="infoWinOpen = false"
  >
    <info-window-content />
  </gmap-info-window>
</GmapMap>
```

**Effort**

I have tried using Css to hide the close icon like so.

```
.gm-ui-hover-effect {
  display: none !important;
}
```

or

```
button.gm-ui-hover-effect {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

yet still the close "x" icon still showing.

Comment: Can you check the x icon on dev-console to see if your class is applied? If so, is it being overridden (maybe by inline-css) ?

Answer (score -1):

the solution I found is to use *Css ::v-deep selectors*

```
div ::v-deep .gm-ui-hover-effect {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This might work (today) but is based on undocumented class names that are subject to change with any API update. There are almost no options to customize the standard infowindow. You better use an external library (if available) or develop your own solution than to create code which is dependent on undocumented properties.

Comment: the `/deep/` selector & `>>>` are the only thing that could make it work. I wasn't able to find other solution for this problem. it seems the question doesn't have answer for now. should I delete my question?

Comment: You don't have to delete your question, it might still help someone else and/or someone might provide a better answer. But as I said, it's a *bad* solution that might stop working without warning, hence my advice to develop your own solution or to find an alternate library (if any?) so to not reinvent the wheel.